# Why is VK_ERROR_UNKNOWN only defined in Vulkan 1.2.131?

Tags: vulkan

`VK_ERROR_UNKNOWN` was part of [Vulkan 1.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/chap3.html#VkResult). However, it was only first defined in Vulkan-Header 1.2.13 (see [history](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Headers/commit/881bbb347a08d1b5aa77f61a52a30b506de9f2bf#)).

Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: None, except the ones provided in the spec and the changelog. Why do you expect the general community to have authoritative answers about internal reasonings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VK_ERROR_UNKNOWN` was added so you have some specific code to return if your driver (or perhaps layer) encounter some inconsistency and panic. Previously `VK_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILED_EXT` was often used for the case.

Either way, returning `VK_ERROR_UNKNOWN` is in of itself a part of undefined behavior, and is not allowed as part of conformant behavior. So it is not compatibility breaking change to introduce the code.

Comment: "Either way, returning VK_ERROR_UNKNOWN is in of itself a part of undefined behavior [...]" What you're refering to is the note in 2.7.3, right? "VK_ERROR_UNKNOWN is not expected to ever be returned if the application behavior is valid, and if the implementation is bug-free." I don't know, I think my question still stands: Why does the spec _define_ an error code for undefined behavior (sounds like a bad idea), then only define that error code in the 1.2 header, essentially making 1.0 and 1.1 incomplete? Am I wrong to find this strange?

Comment: @mkl Yes, and also the fact that `VK_ERROR_UNKNOWN` is not listed as valid return code for any command. AIS in comment "why" is not really suitable question for SO; only the authors would know for sure. You need to elaborate why it sounds bad to you. Usually a driver can have lot of `if (something wrong) return something;`. Might as well have specific error code for that. Undefined behavior is still undefined; as in the driver can do anything including returning this code.

Comment: @mkl You cannot retrospectively define stuff in old headers without a time machine anyway, so not sure what you are asking.

Comment: "You need to elaborate why it sounds bad to you." - By doing so, you're making the effects of undefined behavior part of the specification, which (I think) is a contradiction. To be fair, calling it a bad idea was too rash. I grant that in practise this type of error may be useful.

Comment: "Undefined behavior is still undefined; as in the driver can do anything including returning this code." - I think that makes things a little clearer for me, thanks!

Comment: "[...] not sure what you are asking." - I'm interested in understanding the Vulkan spec. I think it's quite a significant gap in an implementation if v1.0 states that `VK_ERROR_UNKNOWN = -13`, but the implementation doesn't define `VK_ERROR_UNKNOWN` until two minor versions later. I was wondering if there was a particular reason for that, or if it was just an oversight, etc. I never suggested that the old headers should be changed.

Comment: @mkl Then what are you suggesting? You cannot change old headers, so the change can only be in new headers. It is actually not so uncommon; there were e.g. some enumerants that had a typo in them, so a new name was introduced in a new header. It should also be kept in mind, that while the authors do not actively try to break your build, Vulkan only offers ABI compatibility (**not** API\header compatibility).

Comment: @mkl Yea, basically it is an oversight. It was figured few years later after 1.0 release that it might be useful to have a `VK_ERROR_UNKNOWN`. AIS, it does not really break any compatibility guarantees, so the change is not worth introducing a new minor version and can simply be delivered in the patch version of the specification.

Comment: "Vulkan only offers ABI compatibility (*not* API\header compatibility)." There you go! I didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: "Then what are you suggesting?" - I'm not suggesting anything. :) I just asked to satisfy my interest in why the value was missing from earlier version.